# How to lock the iPad screen automatically, when VNC connection is established?

Tags: ios, ipad, screen-lock

I use RealVNC Viewer on my old iPad (iOS 9.3.5 is there).

The device is automatically locked, when it is not used. There is no PIN or any other protection enabled.

However, when VNC connection is established, it doesn't lock the device / turn it off automatically.

Is there any way to fix it?